# Can you use Zlib or Libarchive in RTEMS?

Tags: rtems

Was wondering if it was possible to use Zlib or libarchive to compress and decompress files in rtem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know when it has been imported but there is some version of zlib available in cpukit/zlib: https://git.rtems.org/rtems/tree/cpukit/zlib?id=8d989c56ff0c65beb7ec3390aebef6ea52840fab

You should be able to use that out of the box without adding anything.